# Помогите заменить функцию preg_replace() на preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, dle

Всем привет.
Я - системный администратор, тут дали задачу перенести сайт..
ну и он посыпал этим (ошибками со ссылкой на файл и строку):

```
Notice: Undefined index: do in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 803 Notice: Undefined variable: subaction in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/init.php on line 317 Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/classes/templates.class.php on line 68 Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/classes/templates.class.php on line 72  Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 923 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 923 Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 127 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 169 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined index: date_announce in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 439 Notice: Undefined index: slide_img in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 439 Notice: Undefined index: slide_url in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 439 Notice: Undefined index: answer in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 439 Notice: Undefined index: gallery in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 439 Notice: Undefined index: iframe in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 439 Notice: Undefined index: iframeh in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 439 Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/classes/templates.class.php on line 417 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 923 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 923 Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 127 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 169 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined index: date_announce in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 439 Notice: Undefined index: slide_img in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 439 Notice: Undefined index: slide_url in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 439 Notice: Undefined index: answer in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 439 Notice: Undefined index: gallery in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 439 Notice: Undefined index: iframe in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.short.php on line 439 Notice: Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 71 Notice: Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 84 Notice: Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 84 Notice: Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 88 Notice: Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 88 Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 98 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined index: slide_img in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: slide_url in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: answer in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: gallery in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: iframe in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: iframeh in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 923 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 923 Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 71 Notice: Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 84 Notice: Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 84 Notice: Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 88 Notice: Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 88 Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 98 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined index: date_announce in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: slide_img in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: slide_url in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: answer in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: iframe in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: iframeh in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 923 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 923 Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 71 Notice: Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 84 Notice: Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 84 Notice: Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 88 Notice: Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 88 Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 98 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined index: date_announce in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: slide_img in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: slide_url in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: answer in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: gallery in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: iframe in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: iframeh in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 923 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 923 Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 71 Notice: Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 84 Notice: Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 84 Notice: Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 88 Notice: Use of undefined constant Ymd - assumed 'Ymd' in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 88 Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 98 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/functions.php on line 898 Notice: Undefined index: date_announce in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: slide_img in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: slide_url in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: answer in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: gallery in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: iframe in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Notice: Undefined index: iframeh in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/modules/show.custom.php on line 364 Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/xxx.xxx.com/engine/classes/templates.class.php on line 417
```

Как исправить, я не понимаю. Первый раз сталкиваюсь с движком DLE, да и не буду врать, в программировании php я не силен.

```
###paerse.class.php###
$txt = preg_replace( "#<!--TBegin:(.+?)-->(.+?)<!--TEnd-->#ie", "\$this->decode_thumb('\\1')", $txt ); 
$txt = preg_replace( "#<!--TBegin-->(.+?)<!--TEnd-->#ie", "\$this->decode_oldthumb('\\1')", $txt );
$txt = preg_replace( "#<!--dle_leech_begin--><a href=[\"'](https://|https://|ftp://|ed2k://|news://|magnet:)?(\S.+?)['\"].*?" . ">(.+?)</a><!--dle_leech_end-->#ie", "\$this->decode_leech('\\1\\2', '\\3')", $txt ); 
$txt = preg_replace( "#<!--dle_image_begin:(.+?)-->(.+?)<!--dle_image_end-->#ies", "\$this->decode_dle_img('\\1')", $txt );
$txt = preg_replace( "#<!--dle_flash_begin:(.+?)-->(.+?)<!--dle_flash_end-->#ies", "\$this->decode_flash('\\1')", $txt ); 
$txt = preg_replace( "#<img src=[\"'](\S+?)['\"](.+?)>#ie", "\$this->decode_img('\\1', '\\2')", $txt ); 
$txt = preg_replace( "#<noindex><a href=[\"'](https://|https://|ftp://|ed2k://|news://|magnet:)?(\S.+?)['\"].*?" . ">(.+?)</a></noindex>#ie", "\$this->decode_url('\\1\\2', '\\3')", $txt );
$txt = preg_replace( "#<a href=[\"'](https://|https://|ftp://|ed2k://|news://|magnet:)?(\S.+?)['\"].*?" . ">(.+?)</a>#ie", "\$this->decode_url('\\1\\2', '\\3')", $txt );
if( $wysiwig != "yes" ) $txt = preg_replace( "#\[code\](.+?)\[/code\]#ies", "\$this->decode_code('\\1', '{$use_html}')", $txt );
###paerse.class.php###

###templates.class.php###
$this->template = preg_replace ( "#\\[not-group=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/not-group\\]#ies", "\$this->check_group('\\1', '\\2', false)", $this->template );
$this->template = preg_replace ( "#\\[group=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/group\\]#ies", "\$this->check_group('\\1', '\\2')", $this->template );
$this->template = preg_replace ( "#\\[aviable=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/aviable\\]#ies", "\$this->check_module('\\1', '\\2')", $this->template );
$this->template = preg_replace ( "#\\[not-aviable=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/not-aviable\\]#ies", "\$this->check_module('\\1', '\\2', false)", $this->template );
$this->template = preg_replace ( "#\\[page-count=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/page-count\\]#ies", "\$this->check_page('\\1', '\\2')", $this->template );
$this->template = preg_replace( "#\\{include file=['\"](.+?)['\"]\\}#ies", "\$this->load_file('\\1', 'tpl')", $this->template );
$template = preg_replace ( "#\\[aviable=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/aviable\\]#ies", "\$this->check_module('\\1', '\\2')", $template );
$this->copy_template = preg_replace( "#\\{include file=['\"](.+?)['\"]\\}#ies", "\$this->load_file('\\1', 'php')", $this->copy_template );
###templates.class.php###

###show.custom.php###
$tpl->copy_template = preg_replace ( "#\{date=(.+?)\}#ie", "langdate('\\1', '{$row['date']}')", $tpl->copy_template );
$tpl->copy_template = preg_replace( "#\\[catlist=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/catlist\\]#ies", "check_category('\\1', '\\2', '{$row['category']}')", $tpl->copy_template ); 71 
###show.custom.php###

###index.php###
$tpl->copy_template = preg_replace ( "#\\[category=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/category\\]#ies", "check_category('\\1', '\\2', '{$category_id}')", $tpl->copy_template );
$tpl->copy_template = preg_replace ( "#\\{custom category=['\"](.+?)['\"] template=['\"](.+?)['\"] aviable=['\"](.+?)['\"] from=['\"](.+?)['\"] limit=['\"](.+?)['\"] cache=['\"](.+?)['\"]\\}#ies", "custom_print('\\1', '\\2', '\\3', '\\4', '\\5', '\\6', '{$dle_module}')", $tpl->copy_template ); 
###index.php###
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Вопрос при первичной проверке: вы уверены в правильности формулировки "он посыпал этим"? Рекомендую уточнить. И лучше всё же знаков препинания хоть немного добавить - совсем сложно читать.

Comment: посыпал ошибками с ссылкой на файл и строку. За знаки препинания извиняюсь, поправлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо вы пытаетесь запустить сайт, который работал ранее, к примеру, на PHP 5.4/5.6 на версии PHP 5.6/7.x либо что-то подобное. Так как если раньше работало, то и на новом сервере должно работать все также. Настройте окружение также как и было и скорее всего ошибки уйдут. А перенос сайта с версии 5.6 на 7.x в лучшем случае не закончится одним исправлением функции preg_replace() - придется менять и фиксить очень много ошибок и багов, которые вы сразу и не заметите.

Comment: Старая версия 5.3,5.4  и 5.5 пытаемся завести на 5.6 потому что 5.5 не устанавливается на debian 11 ( не собирается бинарник), есть вариант с обновлением движка, но его держу в закромах потому что придётся переписывать template.

Comment: Ну значит придется отказаться от Debian 11 и делать на такой же ОС, что и была.

Comment: Решено, перестановка PHP5.6 решила все проблемы